# Congruent numbers have congruent squarefree parts?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The problem is:

If $a\equiv b\pmod{p},$ then $Squarefree(a)\equiv Squarefree(b) \pmod{p}.$ Is this true?

I encountered such problem in homework I'm doing, where I need to check if the squarefree value of a polynomial is congruent to some numbers modulo $5$. Now I'm wondering if it would be enough to check it only for values $0,\ldots,4$.

I think the statement is true, I just don't know how to prove it.

Edit: by a squarefree part od $a$ I mean $Squarefree(a)=d,$ where $a=b^2d$ and $b^2$ is the largest perfect square divisor of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. For example,

$$3^3\equiv2^3\pmod{19}$$ but $$3\not\equiv2\pmod{19}$$ where $squarefree(3^3)=3$ and $squarefree(2^3)=2$.

Comment: But $Squarefree(3^2)=1$ and $Squarefree(2^2)=1$ as well, so it your case it is still true

Comment: @Nom I have made an edit. Sorry!