# Values of a polynomial modulo 4

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this polynomial

$f(x,y)=x^8 + 8x^6y^2 -2x^4y^4 + 8x^2y^6 + y^8,$

with $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}, (x,y)=1,$ for which I have to check that the squarefree part is always congruent do 1 modulo 4. By a squarefree part od a I mean $Squarefree(a)=d,$ where $a=b^2d$ and $b^2$ is the largest perfect square divisor of $a.$

This is what I already tried:

- I had checked for each values of $x,y\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ that make sense (i.e. not both even) what the value $f(x,y) \pmod{4}$ is. I only have problems when $x= 1,3, y=1,3$. In those cases $f(x,y)/16$ is congruent to 1 mod 4, but I don't think I can divide with a zero (which is 4 in this case).
- I wanted to see if maybe [this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782883/congruent-numbers-have-congruent-squarefree-parts) is true, which would greatly lighten my problem, but as it turns out, it is not.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or maybe some hints?

Comment: All you need for this is that $f(x,y)\equiv1\pmod4$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, but $x$ and $y$ have to be coprime.

Comment: @Nom But $x=1$ and $y=1$ are coprime: $gcd(1,1)=1$. We need the *squarefree* part.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Exactly, that's what I'm having troubles with.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, you are right about that. But if I'm not mistaken, $f(1,1)=1+8-2+8+1=16\equiv 0 \pmod{4},$ but the squarefree part of 16 is congruent to 1 mod 4

Comment: But you can't divide by $16=4\cdot 4=0$ in $\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that is one of the problems.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But the problem is still valid, we are looking at squarefree parts in $\mathbb{Z},$ and then checking that it is congruent to 1 mod 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$f(x,y)=(x^4-y^4)^2+8x^2y^2(x^4+y^4).$$
If one of $x$ and $y$ are even and the other odd, then $f(x,y)\equiv1\pmod 4$. That's OK.

If $x$ and $y$ are odd, then $x^4+y^4\equiv2\pmod 8$ and so $8x^2y^2(x^4+y^4)\equiv16
\pmod{64}$. Also $x^4$, $y^4\equiv1\pmod{8}$ so $(x^4-y^4)^2\equiv0\pmod{64}$.
Therefore $f(x,y)\equiv16\pmod{64}$. Then $f(x,y)/16\equiv1\pmod4$ and we're still OK.